# How to fetch the null value of a dynamodb table attribute using boto

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am dealing with a table which is something like this.
Table Name: sandboxes

```
Id               name                        type

 1                xyz                         
 2                xx                          
 3                xxx                         
 4                yyyy                        private
```

the problem i am facing is.
1) i can't get the attribute value `type` if it is null. Basically i want to set something if this value is null. But dynamodb scan simply skip putting it in the json response.

given below is the python script that i have written.

```
dynamodb_resource = session.resource('dynamodb')
table_sandboxes = dynamodb_resource.Table('sandboxes')
response_sandboxes = table_sandboxes.scan()
def _myfun(box_id)
    for i in response_sandboxes['Items']:
                if box_id == i['id']:
                        if i['type'] == 'private':
                                return 'true'
                        else:
                                return 'false'

        return 1


_myfun(2)
```

error that i am getting is.

```
KeyError: 'type'
```

So,
1) is there a way i can scan and get the attribute value even if it is null?
2) if scan is the correct way to do this?
3) do i also have to consider the paginator and deal with it if table is larger in size?

I am new to this, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB treats `null` as an actual [data type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes), similar as a number or a strings. In the example above, the `type` attribute in the items with ID 1, 2 and 3 is not `null`, it is just not present. In item ID 4, its data type is string. Having items with various attributes (missing or different between items) is possible in DynamoDB, because it is schemaless.

The easiest way to solve the error in your code would be to test in the `type` is present in the item:

```py
return True if i.get('type') == 'private' else False
```

You can also store the value in the `type` attribute as a `null` type (the nomenclature here gets confusing), but then you could not store a value `private` in that attribute. I assume that's not what you want.

Regarding your second question, `scan`, as you suspect, is not the best way to do it. Modelling of data in DynamoDB is a topic by itself. The [DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html) is a great way to start learning about it. If you want to retrieve items by their `type` attribute, one thing you could do is to create a [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes.html) to do this.